# Código de Arduino: Reiniciar un contador "i" que va iterando sobre un array de funciones hecho a través de punteros

Tags: array, punteros, arduino, function

Estoy haciendo un **sketch de arduino**

Quiero hacer un programa en el cual, a través de un solo botón(usando un contador "i++") voy llamando a diferentes funciones (son acordes de música en protocolo MIDI)

Mi misión actualmente es hacer un **array de funciones** para iterar sobre el mismo, para lo cual estoy usando **punteros**.

Problema: en cuanto paso la variable "i" para iterar sobre el array, ya no puedo sumarle más.

Este es **un programa de ejemplo** (en el original, en vez de las funciones "hola" y "adios" imaginaros acordes "DoMayor" y "LaMenor")

```
void (*ptr[2])() = {hello, goodbye};


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ptr[i]();
    Serial.println(i);
  }
  exit(0);                          /*
                                          */
}
void hello() {
  Serial.println("hello");
  Serial.flush();

}

void goodbye() {
  Serial.println("goodbye");
  Serial.flush();

}
```

Bien, en el **Serial Monitor** aparece lo siguiente:

> 0
>
> goodbye
>
> 1C«±±½5

Comment: Lo he revisado, pero no he encontrado ningún error. Aunque las funciones que usas en el array debes declararlas antes que el array.

Comment: El for se sale de rango. Tienes dos funciones en tu puntero, y el bucle recorre 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un error en el bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ptr[i]();
  Serial.println(i);
}
```

No es un 3, es un 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  ptr[i]();
  Serial.println(i);
}
```

Tus funciones se referencian como ptr[0] y ptr[1] respectivamente. Al invocar a ptr[3] el comportamiento es inesperado sencillamente.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que, antes de utilizar las funciones hello y goodbye, las declares antes de utilizarlas.

```
void hello ( void );
void goodbye ( void );

void (*ptr[2])() = {hello, goodbye};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
[...]
```

Así tu programa podrá saber que son funciones y que cuando tenga que llamarlas, las identifique.